# WinCE registry value monitor

Tags: c#, events, registry

Evening all,

I need some advice on monitoring a registry value in WinCE. I am writing a Windows Forms application which needs to monitor a value in registry, and fire an event when it changes, can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to specify what value you want to monitoring?

Comment: Yes it needs to be a specific value that is monitored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement this using PInvoke code:

```
   [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(UIntPtr hKey, string lpSubKey, uint ulOptions, int samDesired, out UIntPtr phkResult);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern UIntPtr CeFindFirstRegChange(UIntPtr hKey, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bWatchSubtree, uint dwNotifyFilter);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern UInt32 WaitForSingleObject(UIntPtr Handle, UInt32 Wait);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern Int32 CeFindNextRegChange(UIntPtr hChangeHandle);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern Int32 CeFindCloseRegChange(UIntPtr hChangeHandle);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int RegCloseKey(UIntPtr hKey);
```

and by using WaitForSingleObject.